# Rewrite index.php?lang=en to /en

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have problem with redirecting onepage multilingual website. My htaccess redirection doesnt work correctly. I need help how to do it. When I add these two lines in my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en$
RewriteRule ^ /en? [R=301,L]
```

redirect working, but mysite.com/en show 404 not found. 
Someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you please post what is in your root directory? I am currently not sure if you want it to go to mysite.com/en/index or mysite.com/index?lang=en

Comment: Thanks for reply, I want it to rewrite mysite.com/index.php?lang=en to new mysite.com/en. I just want pretty clean seo url for website. I have two languages and english is a second language.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}$ index.php?lang=$1
```

if you want to restrict it to two lowercase characters only. If you're not using other parameters in the form of `mysite.com/xy`, then you can skip the `RewriteCondition`.

Maybe also apply

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

to make Apache only rewrite non-existant files & folders.